# How to implement LIKE operation in rsql-jpa-specification for a list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a model entity which has a LIST type field, which stores the value in the form a string (comma separated) in sql.
I am trying to implement a custom converter which would return all the samples which has a particular list element.

If the values are "A,B,C","A","B,C",. If I provide "A", I want to retrieve both the samples containing both "A,B,C" as well as "A".

This custom converter just returns the sample which has value "A".

```
RSQLJPASupport.addConverter(List.class, s -> {
            try {
                return Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
            }catch (final IllegalArgumentException ex){
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Please help! I followed these steps btw: https://github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification

Answer (score 0):

Assume the name of the field codes, you could use
repository.findAll(toSpecification("codes=='A' or codes=='A,*' or codes=='*,A' or codes=='*,A,*'"))